# Parametric functions in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to know how to manipulate parametric 1-D functions. For instance I want to plot the gaussian for differente values of the parameter a:
f(x)=exp(-a*(x-1)**2)

I know that I can create different functions f(x) for many values of a, but I wonder if there is a way to plot this function for a=1,2,3,  etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Be careful to distinguish "parametric functions" from "functions with parameters". The first refers to plots such as x = cos(t), y = sin(t) (plotted with set parametric), the second is of the type you ask about.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, just define your function so that it takes the variable parameter as input:

```
f(x,a)=exp(-a*(x-1)**2)
```

And then loop over it. It can be done in a sequence ("a from 1 to 3 at intervals of 1"):

```
plot for [a=1:3:1] f(x,a) t "a = ".a
```

Or using a list of values:

```
plot for [a in "1 2 3"] f(x,a) t "a = ".a
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using the following commands

```
gnuplot> f(x) = a*x
gnuplot> plot for [a = 1:3:1] f(x) title sprintf("a=%d",a)
```

I get the following plot

[image]

You may want to read the descriptions you can get by the following commands

```
gnuplot> help for
 The `plot`, `splot`, `set` and `unset` commands may optionally contain an
 iteration for clause.  This has the effect of [...]
```

and

```
gnuplot> help sprintf
 `sprintf("format",var1,var2,...)` applies standard C-language format specifiers
 to multiple arguments and returns the resulting string. If you want to
 use gnuplot's own format specifiers, you must instead call `gprintf()`.
 For information on sprintf format specifiers, please see standard C-language
 documentation or the unix sprintf man page.
```

HTH